# how can remove this element to avoid having two menu buttons with one that shows unnecessary pages

Tags: menus

I like the menu buttons when the website is viewed in the desktop view but I don't like it whenever it is viewed in the mobile view. it brings two menu buttons and one of the buttons shows unnecessary pages while the other one just works fine

bellow is the inspected element that I thought has to be removed to avoid this menu button but I don't know how to go about it or you can visit my website  [Here](https://www.onimark.com/) and try to minimize the browser to mobile ratio to see what exactly I have to do to work out this issue.

```
<button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="site-navigation" aria-expanded="true"><span>Menu</span></button>
```

Comment: Disable your "mega menu" plugin and see if that removes the duplicate. If so, you will need to look into a different combination of themes and plugins, or create a child theme that does not have a built-in menu, because it looks like your theme adds one menu by default and your plugin is adding an additional menu.

Comment: i tried to disable the mega max but still got the frustrating menu and all i don't like about it are unnecessary pages under it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this CSS code to hide that menu:

```
.secondary-navigation, .menu-toggle {
    display: none;
}
```

Of course, that option doesn't remove it but just hide it.

To try to remove it, since I think you don't want to get rid of the `Max Mega Menu` you can try to go to **Appearance > Menus** and find the menu on top and check if it has any **Display location** checkbox marked so you can uncheck it.

I didn't find any options for a Secondary menu on its documentation so it's kind of weird.

Comment: i have gone as far as deleting it but still its appearing with its unnecessary pages

Comment: Why don't you remove it using the CSS code? It's not elegant solution but it works :p

Comment: i have tried adding the code .secondary-navigation {
    display: none;
} but it is still there, you can check it https://www.onimark.com

Comment: I just checked and it is gone:  https://screenshots.firefox.com/YZHq211e159bmezG/www.onimark.com

Comment: try to minimize the view to the mobile size

Comment: Got it, which one do you want to hide the white or black one?

Comment: the white one and leave the black one

Comment: Answer update, check the code again and add that one instead.

Comment: which code? drop it

Comment: I updated the answer: .secondary-navigation, .menu-toggle {
    display: none;
}

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as correct.

Comment: so now i can add another menu with previous pages right?

Comment: You haven't done that, https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers read 2. accept it. About the other question, sure you can.

Comment: i think its done now